# How to change windows service recovery option using c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have WCF service that is hosted on windows service. I installed this service using Windows installer. Sometimes, when i stop service using C# code, it stucks on stopping. So i thought, why not kill service if service is not stopping within 2 minutes. My code is below to stop service:

```
var service = ServiceController.GetServices()
                .FirstOrDefault(s => s.ServiceName == serviceName);
            try
            {
                if (service == null || service.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running) return;
                if(service.CanStop)
                {
                    session.LogInfo($"Stopping '{serviceName}'.");
                    TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(ServiceStopTime);
                    service.Stop();
                    service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);
                    session.LogInfo($"'{serviceName}' stopped successfully.");
                }
```

It is working as expected. I want to kill my process if service does not stop. Here is my code to kill process.

```
var processName = GetProcessNameByWindowsService(serviceName);
            if (processName == null) return;
            Process[] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
            if (procs.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (Process proc in procs)
                {
                    session.LogInfo($"Killing Process'{processName}'.");
                    proc.Kill();
                    session.LogInfo($"'{processName}' killed successfully.");
                }
            }
```

It is working as expected too but the problem is when i kill the process, the service does not stop. It assigns new process to service and service keep runs. After googled and investing some time i found the cause that is the window service recovery option which is restart the service if it fails. I want to change/set the recovery option for service in case of first failure, second failure and subsequent failure to take no action using C# code. I googled but did not find anything. So i want to know how i can change the recovery option of installed window service using C#?

Comment: Why not spend time fixing whatever issues there are with about it not being able to shut down cleanly in 30 seconds instead?

Comment: You are right. But unfortunately the service code is not in my hand. I have asked to do this. I suggested exactly what you have said but i asked to kill process if not stopped within 2 minutes.

Comment: So, if an administrator is stopping this service themselves for some reason, the service might also go into this unresponsive state? Or during windows shutdown? The service as described is *broken*. It sounds like you're working with someone unable to accept this basic fact.

Comment: Agreed. I explained him but client wants to do everything programmatically

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After investing time finally i have found the solution with the help of [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/217f4163-45a8-4352-aed8-d6581ff13ce8/set-recovery-options-in-properties-of-windows-service?forum=Vsexpressvcs) link. I have written two helper classes to set/update recovery option of windows service. First of all i wrote a static helper class which is below:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace HRTC.CustomActions.Helpers
{
    public static class ServiceRecoveryOptionHelper
    {
        //Action Enum
        public enum RecoverAction
        {
            None = 0, Restart = 1, Reboot = 2, RunCommand = 3
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]

        public struct ServiceFailureActions
        {
            public int dwResetPeriod;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]

            public string lpRebootMsg;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]

            public string lpCommand;
            public int cActions;
            public IntPtr lpsaActions;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public class ScAction
        {
            public int type;
            public uint dwDelay;
        }

        // Win32 function to open the service control manager
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr OpenSCManager(string lpMachineName, string lpDatabaseName, int dwDesiredAccess);

        // Win32 function to open a service instance
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr OpenService(IntPtr hScManager, string lpServiceName, int dwDesiredAccess);

        // Win32 function to change the service config for the failure actions.
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "ChangeServiceConfig2")]

        public static extern bool ChangeServiceFailureActions(IntPtr hService, int dwInfoLevel,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
            ref ServiceFailureActions lpInfo);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "QueryServiceConfig2W")]
        public static extern Boolean QueryServiceConfig2(IntPtr hService, UInt32 dwInfoLevel, IntPtr buffer, UInt32 cbBufSize, out UInt32 pcbBytesNeeded);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern int GetLastError();
    }
    public class FailureAction
    {
        // Default constructor
        public FailureAction() { }

        // Constructor
        public FailureAction(ServiceRecoveryOptionHelper.RecoverAction actionType, int actionDelay)
        {
            Type = actionType;
            Delay = actionDelay;
        }

        // Property to set recover action type
        public ServiceRecoveryOptionHelper.RecoverAction Type { get; set; } = ServiceRecoveryOptionHelper.RecoverAction.None;

        // Property to set recover action delay
        public int Delay { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then i already have static class for windows services that have different methods like to start windows service, stop windows service and install service etc. I added new static method in this class to change recovery option of windows service which receive 4 parameters. First one is the service name, and other three are the recovery options of first,second and subsequent recovery options respectively. Below is it's implementation.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace HRTC.CustomActions.Helpers
{
    public class LocalServiceHelper
    {
        //Change service recovery option settings
        private const int ServiceAllAccess = 0xF01FF;
        private const int ScManagerAllAccess = 0xF003F;
        private const int ServiceConfigFailureActions = 0x2;
        private const int ErrorAccessDenied = 5;


        public static void ChangeRevoveryOption(string serviceName, ServiceRecoveryOptionHelper.RecoverAction firstFailureAction,
            ServiceRecoveryOptionHelper.RecoverAction secondFailureAction, ServiceRecoveryOptionHelper.RecoverAction thirdFailureAction)
        {
            try
            {
                // Open the service control manager
                var scmHndl = ServiceRecoveryOptionHelper.OpenSCManager(null, null, ScManagerAllAccess);
                if (scmHndl.ToInt32() <= 0)
                    return;

                // Open the service
                var svcHndl = ServiceRecoveryOptionHelper.OpenService(scmHndl, serviceName, ServiceAllAccess);

                if (svcHndl.ToInt32() <= 0)
                    return;

                var failureActions = new ArrayList
                {
                    // First Failure Actions and Delay (msec)
                    new FailureAction(firstFailureAction, 0),
                    // Second Failure Actions and Delay (msec)
                    new FailureAction(secondFailureAction, 0),
                    // Subsequent Failures Actions and Delay (msec)
                    new FailureAction(thirdFailureAction, 0)
                };

                var numActions = failureActions.Count;
                var myActions = new int[numActions * 2];
                var currInd = 0;

                foreach (FailureAction fa in failureActions)
                {
                    myActions[currInd] = (int) fa.Type;
                    myActions[++currInd] = fa.Delay;
                    currInd++;
                }

                // Need to pack 8 bytes per struct
                var tmpBuf = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(numActions * 8);

                // Move array into marshallable pointer
                Marshal.Copy(myActions, 0, tmpBuf, numActions * 2);

                // Set the SERVICE_FAILURE_ACTIONS struct
                var config =
                    new ServiceRecoveryOptionHelper.ServiceFailureActions
                    {
                        cActions = 3,
                        dwResetPeriod = 0,
                        lpCommand = null,
                        lpRebootMsg = null,
                        lpsaActions = new IntPtr(tmpBuf.ToInt32())
                    };

                // Call the ChangeServiceFailureActions() abstraction of ChangeServiceConfig2()
                var result =
                    ServiceRecoveryOptionHelper.ChangeServiceFailureActions(svcHndl, ServiceConfigFailureActions,
                        ref config);

                //Check the return
                if (!result)
                {
                    var err = ServiceRecoveryOptionHelper.GetLastError();
                    if (err == ErrorAccessDenied)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Access Denied while setting Failure Actions");

                    }

                    // Free the memory
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(tmpBuf);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to set service recovery options");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

That's it. You just only need to call the method to change recovery option of windows service. For example:

```
LocalServiceHelper.ChangeRevoveryOption("ServiceName",
                    ServiceRecoveryOptionHelper.RecoverAction.Restart,
                    ServiceRecoveryOptionHelper.RecoverAction.Restart,
                    ServiceRecoveryOptionHelper.RecoverAction.None);
```

It will update the recovery option of windows service as you will mention when calling the method. Hope this help. Happy codding!  :)

Comment: I tried this and it threw "Unable to set service recovery options: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow." so may not work on newer systems

Comment: @CloudTheWolf this solution will work but there is a little point, and that is , you should consider your CPU architecture , if you use a 64x bit then you must set every line that points to a 32-bit memory block into 64x one . For example change (scmHndl.ToInt32() <= 0) into scmHndl.ToInt64() <= 0)

Comment: @CloudTheWolf i had try this solution and it's working fine with debug mode in VS. but when i try to build exe and execute it. it unable to open the service control manager. at below stage in above code sample.

 // Open the service control manager
 var scmHndl = ServiceRecoveryOptionHelper.OpenSCManager(null, null, ScManagerAllAccess);